# PHP Mailer not working inside php script

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am working on getting the reset password for my application through mail link. When i try to give without php mailer the button is working and when i use php mailer the button is not showing any status. When I submit without phpmailer I am getting status success and mail actually doesn't go and when I use php mailer i am not getting any message status. Here is my php code:

```
    session_start();
    require_once "function.php";
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','demo');
        $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        $sql = $con->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");


        if($sql->num_rows>0){
            $token = generateString();
            $con->query("UPDATE users SET token='$token' WHERE email='$email'");

            $mail = new  PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com";
                $mail->Password = "xxx";
                $mail->SetFrom("xxx@gmail.com", "Employee Leave Management System");

                $id=$_SESSION['id'];

                $select_query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
                $select_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query);
                $name=$select_sql['username'];
                var_dump($name);

                $select_query1 = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                $select_sql1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query1);
                $email=$select_sql1['email'];
                    var_dump($email);

                $mail->Subject = "HIE ";
                $mail->Body = "HIEHIE.";
                $mail->To = $email;
                $mail->AddAddress($email);

                if($mail->Send())
                {
                 exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg"=>'Please check your email')));
                }


            }else{

            exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg"=>'Please check your input!!!')));
        }
    }

?>
```

html code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forgot Password</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_f/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 align="center" style="margin-top: 200px;">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" id="email" class="input-field"><br><br>
                <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button><br><br>
                <p id="response"></p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var email = $("#email");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').on('click',function(){
            if(email.val()!=""){
                email.css('border','1px solid green');

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'forgot_pwd.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {
                        email: email.val()
                    },success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        if(!response.success) {
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color','red');
                        }else{
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color','green');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                email.css('border','1px solid red');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try get the error via `$mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale No error is coming...It is same as previous output

Comment: If you're not getting any output with `SMTPDebug = 2`, it means it's not getting as far as connecting, probably because your ISP blocks outbound SMTP, or your server has outdated CA certificates. Follow what the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide says about how to diagnose connectivity problems.

Comment: @Synchro Thanks for the solution, I will check with that.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you could have fetched "name" and "email" in the same query.

Comment: Are you sure it is `$mail_to = $email;` and not `$mail->To = $email;`?

Comment: @kush.impetus yes i will do the editing once everything works fine for me. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I suggest try what I said. You can always undo if it does not work. Besides, `$mail_to` isn't being used anywhere. And `$mail` is an object and **To** should be its propety.

Comment: @kush.impetus I tried it and it is showing the same output.

Comment: I am having one strange issue with currently with another mailing library, Pear. I can send emails to Outlook, Hotmail, Yahoo and emails of some proprietary domains. But not to Gmail. That might be the problem with you also.

Comment: Does `var_dump($email) ` output desired value? Blank **To** field can also show status as successful.

Comment: @kush.impetus It is not showing any value...

Comment: Check your query then. It may not be returning a value. And check if the target field in database has a value.

Comment: Try put this above your PHP script, and see if there are any errors produced. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @ToineH No errors are displayed

Comment: @ToineH If i enter the wrong email id it is working and if i enter correct email id it is not showing anything..

Comment: What is it showing? And you mean the email address?

Comment: It should show message "Please check your mail" on success and mail should go that is not happening in my case.

Comment: SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' <--- you are only selecting the id from that row, yet you are trying to access $select_sql1['email']. email is not defined since you are not querying for it. Should atleast be SELECT id, email FROM ... if you need both.

Comment: @OleHaugset This is also not showing any output status.

Comment: Can you provide remote access of your computer? I don't think it is a very nasty problem.

Comment: @kush.impetus team viewer id: 126354689.At what time can you come to teamviewer?

Comment: Whenever you are ready, just drop me a mail on kumarkush@hotmail.co.in.